# Orientdb: Import database in memory and use it as graph

Tags: java, orientdb

This is my Java DB class in which I open database and import database export file in memory graph database, where I define all database schema information for testing cases.

Operation going well but how can I access the imported database as graph instance and not document instance of database?

I try so many things but I have failed...

## Error :

The Person class exist in my schema so something else is going wrong.

```
Caused by:
> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException:
> Class 'PERSON' was not found in current database
```

## Code:

```
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.tool.ODatabaseExportException;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.tool.ODatabaseImport;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQL;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Vertex;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphFactory;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphNoTx;
import lombok.Getter;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Db {

    @Getter private static OrientGraphFactory factory;
    @Getter private static OrientGraphNoTx graph;

    static public void main(String[] args){
        open("memory","database");
        importDB("/schemas/diary-11202016.gz");
        try {
            seed();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        closeDB();
    }

    public static void open(String dbType, String dbUrl) {

        String dbInfo = dbType + ":" + dbUrl;
        System.out.println(dbInfo);

        factory = new OrientGraphFactory(dbInfo, "root", "root").setupPool(1, 10);
        graph = factory.getNoTx();
    }

    public static void importDB(String path) {
        try {
            ODatabaseImport importDb = new ODatabaseImport(graph.getRawGraph(), Db.class.getResourceAsStream(path), (iText) -> {
                System.out.print(iText);
            });
            importDb.setMerge(true);
            importDb.importDatabase();
            importDb.close();
            System.out.println("\nImporting database: OK");
        } catch (ODatabaseExportException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void seed() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Starting to seed...");
        for (Vertex v : (Iterable<Vertex>) graph.command( new OCommandSQL("select from Person")).execute()) {
            System.out.println("- Bought: " + v.getProperty("name"));
        }
        System.out.println("Finish to seed...");
    }

    public static void closeDB() {
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what's in the path variable?

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi forget obout path variable pls... the setup in my application is perfect, focus on orientdb api where I have problems.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following piece of code

```
ODatabaseImport importDb = new ODatabaseImport(graph.getRawGraph(), Db.class.getResourceAsStream(path), (iText) -> {
                System.out.print(iText);
            });
importDb.setMerge(true);
```

with

```
ODatabaseImport importDb = new ODatabaseImport(graph.getRawGraph(), path, (iText) -> {
                System.out.print(iText);
            });
// importDb.setMerge(true);
```

Comment: The error perssists... This is not a fix. Did you try to execute it?

Comment: Are you sure that in your database that you are importing there is the class "Person" ?

Comment: Yes the same is with `select from V`

Comment: Yes, I have executed it and I have no problem.
Can you send your diary-11202016.gz at alessandrorota04@gmail.com or can I send you my test database ?